# Is there a phrase like "fill me in" for remind me?

Tags: phrase-request

I looked for synonyms, but strangely enough there's nothing that sounds like "fill me in", but I swear there was a phrase like that, which meant "remind me".

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/remind

Ex:

> Can you **_ me _** on what I said yesterday?
>
> Can you **_ me _** on what I wanted to do yesterday?
>
> Can you **_ me _** what happened here last night?

Comment: Apprise ?? I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, so pure guess.

Answer (score -1):

Can you fill me in with the details of what happened
Can you fill me in on the details of what happened.

The first to sentences don't make sense in English.

Comment: Your answer isn’t very clear I’m sorry. You have not suggested synonyms. It includes a couple of editing errors too.